# Camera access and image quality handling in HTML5 mobile webpage

Tags: javascript, html, camera, hybrid-mobile-app

I used input tag with file="type" option to capture photo in my HTML5 mobile **webpage**. In some devices web page crashes because of memory issue when the photo is captured(Where camera is > 12MP). Is there any way that I can **control image resolution/quality** while using camera from HTML5?

Current tag:

```
<input id="ext-element-175" type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

Is there any alternative other than `input` tag to access camera from HTML5 page for mobile web app and has more options to have control on camera?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to specify the desired resolution when using HTML Media Capture to capture an image from the device cameras.

The latest [W3C recommendation spec for HTML Media Capture](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/) does not require such options.

You can, however, suggest such an addition to the spec, to be considered for a possible next version of the specification, by submitting an issue on GitHub at https://github.com/w3c/html-media-capture/issues. This was suggested to me by Anssi from Intel - one of the spec editors - after contacting him about a similar issue.

From my experience some Android devices do offer a way, at the OS level, to choose the resolution when recording video (`accept="video/*"`). Such devices might also offer such options when capturing photos.

The current Android device I have access to right now (Lenovo P2) does not offer such OS level options (only flash and switch camera):

[image: ![enter image description here]

That being said your code is not in line with the spec. You should use `capture` or `capture=capture`, not `capture="camera"`. See [Correct Syntax for HTML Media Capture](https://blog.addpipe.com/correct-syntax-html-media-capture/) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

Use `<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="4000000" />` It wont upload if file is bigger than 4mb.

Comment: But the problem is page crashes when photo is captured. Once the photo is captured and webpage has access to it I can reduce the size of the photo and upload it to my server. Is there any way to capture the photo itself with reduced quality?

Comment: ok so you can search php image uploader, and it can show the resized one when the upload finished.